# SugarCRM Calculated field using IfElse, needs to return null on true

Tags: sugarcrm

I have an ifElse function of this construct:

```
ifElse ( condition, return null, otherwise return today's date )
```

As things are currently my function returns itself. The field is a date called course_date:

```
ifElse ( condition, $course_date, today() )
```

and this returns 0 on condition true. This then causes an error as 0 is not a date and then fails when being submitted.

I would like to know if it is possible to return null or an empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create another datetime field called **null_datetime** (for example) with a default value of **none**.Then change the formula to display that field on true.

```
ifElse ( condition, $null_datetime, today() )
```